# Trouble integrating freeradius and Mac Open Directory for 802.1x auth

Tags: freeradius

I'm currently trying to implement 802.1x wifi authentication using an existing Open Directory of users on a Mac machine which is also concurrently running freeradius 3.0.15. The documentation for integrating Open Directory is super vague and lacking, and pretty much says 'this will work if Open Directory and freeradius are installed on the same machine.'

When running local test authentications with users added to the users file, I'm able to authenticate. Running test authentications against users in Open Directory, however, fails to authenticate.

My question is, how do I configure freeradius to actively check Open Directory?

Comment: Hello, I am on the same quest! I wrote a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617087/freeradius-problems-with-open-directory-no-rlm-opendirectory-existing. Did you find an answer? In my case the open directory dylib are nowhere to be found!