# Freeradius: problems with Open Directory, no rlm_opendirectory.* existing

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, freeradius, osx-server

Im trying to pass from macOS Server to FreeRADIUS and I am following Apple's **macOS Server— Service Migration Guide | March 2018**

When trying to configure FreeRadius I have to verify the existence of some files related to Open Directory

> $ ls /usr/local/lib/rlm_opendirectory.
>
> You should see the following in the output:
>
> rlm_opendirectory.a
>
> rlm_opendirectory.dylib
>
> rlm_opendirectory.la

But nothing is there!

Later in "Set up users"
When Testing the setting through:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.17/bin/radiusd -XC
```

I get:

```
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.17
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
Starting - reading configuration files ...


/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.17/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/opendirectory[20]: Failed to link to module 'rlm_opendirectory': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.17/lib/rlm_opendirectory.dylib, 6): image not found
```

Where do I find these files?
Where do I find the Open Directory library?

Thanks's in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that I tried to install through brew, which in its default setting does not use `--enable-developer=yes` option.

I had to edit the formula and reinstall in order to get the openDirectory driver.

```
$ brew edit freeradius-server
add: --enable-developer=yes
save the formula
$ brew reinstall -s freeradius-server
```

Comment: if you're installing for the first time, you can do the edit and then brew install but you need the -s to ensure that it doesn't use a bottle and actually builds it from source using the updated formula

Comment: Thanks! Why on earth this isn't the default on macOS systems, I don't know...